# C# Equivalent of PHP's raw output MD5?

Tags: c#, php, wordpress, hash, md5

I am attempting to implement a 'simpler' version of a (remote) WordPress login.

I have gotten so far, but I am a bit stuck when it comes to the WordPress algorithm to encrypt a password. This code snippet from 'class-phpass.php' (which WP uses to hash a password)...

```
$hash = md5($salt . $password, TRUE);
do {
    $hash = md5($hash . $password, TRUE);
} while (--$count);
```

According to PHP 5 manual -

```
string md5 ( string $str [, bool $raw_output = false ] )
```

"If the optional raw_output is set to TRUE, then the md5 digest is instead returned in raw binary format with a length of 16."

To implement this in C#, thus far, I am using the code below, can be found [here](http://wiki.unity3d.com/index.php?title=MD5):

```
public string Md5Sum(string strToEncrypt)
{
    System.Text.UTF8Encoding ue = new System.Text.UTF8Encoding();
    byte[] bytes = ue.GetBytes(strToEncrypt);

    // encrypt bytes
    MD5CryptoServiceProvider md5 = new MD5CryptoServiceProvider();
    byte[] hashBytes = md5.ComputeHash(bytes);

    // Convert the encrypted bytes back to a string (base 16)
    string hashString = "";

    for (int i = 0; i < hashBytes.Length; i++)
    {
        hashString += System.Convert.ToString(hashBytes[i], 16).PadLeft(2, '0');
    }

    return hashString.PadLeft(32, '0');
}
```

As you can see, this C# version is the equivalent of the PHP version, but passing in FALSE as the second parameter. I have checked this by comparing the output of both versions.

In addition, the WordPress version passes TRUE. I am struggling to apply this change to the C# version.

What is the C# equivalent of the following PHP code?

```
$hash = md5($salt . $password, TRUE);
```

Comment: WordPress hasn't used MD5 for password hashes in years... though it could still be the case if you were working with a legacy installation (but I haven't worked with any legacy WP sites so I can't verify this).

Comment: OK, I misread your question. Your version of WordPress is indeed using PHPass, and essentially you're porting PHPass to C# - you're not actually trying to hash passwords using MD5 alone. Your question makes much more sense now.

Comment: As BoltClock has stated, I need to port PHPPass to C# (in a nutshell) and there is not much I can do to change this - MD5 is what i have to use. That said, if were  (somehow) upgrade to the latest WP build, would this make my life an easier?

Comment: My original comment was a mistake, sorry. WordPress still uses PHPass for hashing passwords but it doesn't provide anything other than a PHP function for authenticating a user. There's a REST API plugin in the works but I don't know if it will be of use here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

raw output means actual bytes, you don't need to convert them into base16 string:

```
public static byte[] Md5Sum_Raw(string strToEncrypt)
{
    System.Text.UTF8Encoding ue = new System.Text.UTF8Encoding();
    byte[] bytes = ue.GetBytes(strToEncrypt);

    // encrypt bytes
    MD5CryptoServiceProvider md5 = new MD5CryptoServiceProvider();
    return md5.ComputeHash(bytes);
}
```

PHP:

```php
$s = md5('1234567890', true);
for ($i=0; $i < strlen($s); $i++)
    echo ord($s[$i]) . ' ';
```

```
232 7 241 252 248 45 19 47 155 176 24 202 103 56 161 159
```

C#:

```
byte[] hash = Md5Sum_Raw("1234567890");
for (int i = 0; i < hash.Length; i++)
    System.Console.Out.Write(hash[i] + " ");
System.Console.Out.WriteLine();

232 7 241 252 248 45 19 47 155 176 24 202 103 56 161 159
```

Comment: Thanks, Lashane - that's what I initially thought. But it confuses me a little on the next (looped) calls to MD5 with the previous result. That is - in PHP, byte[] are strings so they can be passed in directly to next call. But how would that work with C#?

Comment: As you see md5 provider works with bytes, you're converting string to it to make it work

Comment: Yes, I see that. But if you look closely at the looped calls to MD5, the PHP byte[] (or string) has the password appended to it which in, C# will be a string. Granted I convert that to a byte[] also, but what does the PHP concatenation of byte[] map to in C# (where they are not treated as strings).

Comment: Just append byte array to byte array.

Comment: Yes, thanks I just tried and got it to work. On the whole. my confusion lay in the fact that PHP treats byte[] as strings. But thank you. :)

Answer (score 0):

[Please see this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NTtSI.jpg)
 public static string MD5Hash(string input)...

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please don't paste links to images of `code`. It would be much better to copy/paste your  `code` into your answer.

Comment: Code-only answers are considered low quality: make sure to provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem.